# project reactor: my application keeps working after OOM error and I can't intercept and handle such errors

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, project-reactor, r2dbc

I noticed that [project reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) doesn't allow handling OOM errors. Project reactor developers [intercept and handle such errors by adding log messages](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/main/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty/channel/ChannelOperationsHandler.java#L113), but there is no way to intercept and handle them for framework users.

I suppose It's potentially a big problem. If OOM happens, an HTTP request sent by the client of my application hangs, but my application keeps working and handling other requests, and healthchecks of my application are successful too.

As I was answered in a [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2917#issuecomment-1032422400),  my application is potentially in an unrecoverable state. Yes, I agree and I would prefer that healthchecks fail or the application finish when OOM happens. I understand that the onError method is not a good place to handle such special errors. But In my opinion, It could be done in class Hooks, e.g. onJvmError, that will allow to start gracefully shutdown process or signalize via implementation of healthchecks about this situation.

I implemented [the project in Kotlin](https://github.com/typik89/webfluxMemoryRetroProject) ( [in Java](https://github.com/sdeleuze/webfluxMemoryRetroProject)) with the rest endpoint using reactor and Webflux to reproduce such case.

```
interface CsvRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<CsvRow, Long>

@Service
class CsvService(val csvRepository: CsvRepository) {
    fun createByteArray(): Mono<ByteArray> =
        csvRepository.findAll()
            .reduce(ByteArrayOutputStream()) { output, el ->
                output.write(el.toString().toByteArray())
                output.write("\n".toByteArray())
                output
            }
            .map { it.toByteArray() }
}

@SpringBootApplication
class WebfluxMemoryRetroProjectApplication(val csvService: CsvService) {

    @Bean
    fun routing(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = router {
        accept(MediaType.ALL).nest {
            GET("/test") {
                csvService.createByteArray()
                    .flatMap { result ->
                        ServerResponse.ok()
                            .headers { httpHeaders ->
                                httpHeaders.contentType = MediaType("application", "force-download")
                                httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=test.txt")
                            }
                            .bodyValue(ByteArrayResource(result))
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result of HTTP GET requests It requests data from a database and creates a file with a size of about 70MB.
So If I run it with -xmx100m, I have only an error in logs:

```
2022-02-07 12:25:06.135 ERROR 10288 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [7edd71ea, L:/127.0.0.1:58918 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:5432] Error was received while reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
....


2022-02-07 12:25:06.141 ERROR 10288 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] i.r.p.client.ReactorNettyClient          : Connection Error

reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InternalNettyException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This error isn't handled and an HTTP client request hangs.
Is this expected behavior?
how can I handle this exception? I've tried `onErrorResume` and `Hooks.onOperatorError` but I couldn't intercept this type of exception.
It seems unlogical for me that the application keeps working and I can't intercept and handle such errors.

Comment: Afaik you don't. BUt I would argue that how you are sending the file is wrong. Instead you should be writing to the output directly instead of an in-memory `ByteArrayOutputStream` this would not require that amount of memory and your application will continue to work.

Comment: It's just an example to reproduce OOM and In my opinion, I do nothing wrong. It's my choice how to implement the logic of my application. I gave my opinion in detail why it could be a big problem and why if this feature exists It could help. And I think it's possible to add this feature.If even you think that the example application is implemented in a bad way, It doesn't remove the question about intercepting and handling OOM because the application keeps working in such cases

Comment: I think the problem is, once your OOM is thrown, you can't make any guarantees that your code is going to be able to "gracefully shutdown". Sure at the moment,  you can see other things continuing to work, but you have no guarantee that will happen in production when you need it. And by that point you're relying on that to handle this situation instead of something outside the JVM.

Comment: ok, let's forget about gracefully shutdown. I want that my application in such cases goes down but it keeps working. If in a production environment the application doesn't keep working I will happy about this. And for me, It's not so important if my code of handling oom is executed or not. I'm ready to have a situation when my application doesn't execute this code in case only if it goes down without it. But my app keeps working andI don't have the opportunity to recognize that OOM happened. It's big problem because as you said it's a JVM error and there are no guarantees that something works.

Comment: I suspect that the error actually is that it is being handled, by Netty. Judging by the fact that in the end, you get a `ReactorNetty$InternalNettyException`. The OOM is basically end-of-the-road (at least in my experience). The only way to handle it is to log something and kill the app. However I'm also a believer that if you do things right you won't get an out-of-memory error in the first place, those errors are generally produced due to user error, so to fix you should actually fix your own code.

Comment: I would glad to handle any exception but I can't or doesn't know how. As I said many times It's only example and the application doesn't finish in such cases.  Yes, OOM happens when something wrong with an application. But you can found some memory leak on the producation environment after days and you have a chance that on the production requests to application fails but all healthchecks are succed and you don't have a chance to understand this

Comment: I agree with you. There should be an option to just shut down the JVM in case of OOM. It's extremely annoying to have the app still reporting being healthy

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find something better. In the same way, after an OutOfMemory error, my application hangs, the message on the queue keeps "unacked" and health checks keeps working properly and returning 200.

The best option I found was setting the JVM property `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` so as soon as this error happens, JVM will exit with return code 1 and log a message.

I would love to have a way to handle this events and, for example, redirect the problematic message to another queue.